# JPA HibernateSearch Projections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm trying to use JPA with HibernateSearch.  I used Example 5.3 in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en/html/search-query.html.  The results come out as expected.

However, the data coming back is a huge graph.  I only need the primary key of the data.  So, I tried Example 5.9, but it only shows the Hibernate API.  There was not a `javax.persistence.Query.setProjection()` method.

What can I use to get just the primary key of a search result?  Should I try to get the hibernate `session` from the `EntityManager` in JPA?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 5.3 was a bit misleading.  `javax.persistence.Query` doesn't have to be used.  Instead, `org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery` has the `setProjection()` method that I needed.  Here is the resulting code (with fully qualified class names):

```
        //Open JPA session
        javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory emf=javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
        javax.persistence.EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        //Make a FullText EM from the JPA session.
        org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager fullTextSession=org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

        //Build the lucene query.
        org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser parser=new org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser("data1",new org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer());
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query=parser.parse("FindMe");

        //Convert to a hibernate query.
        org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery query2=fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, SampleBean.class);

        //Set the projections
        query2.setProjection("id");

        //Run the query.
        for (Object[] row:(List)query2.getResultList()){
            //Show the list of id's
            System.out.println(row[0]);
        }

        //Close
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
```

`query2` does the projection and all is well!